# How to Password Protect copying a folder on pc

Tags: passwords

I have some files on my computer that I don't want my friends who use my computer to be able to copy them, how ever they can only view and edit the documents on my computer, but they cannot copy or delete the files. so I want a possibility that I can set a password that each time they want to copy the file , they will be asked to provide password to copy the file
I will be very happy if someone can help

I tried using the property settings for administrative permission, but it locks the files permanently meaning each time I want to copy the files, I will have to go and remove the restrictions, I just want something that a password will remove the restrictions